# how to select option inside select element with javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have a select element with four options.

I want to select different options so that different functions can fire ,  but the onclick method is not working.

```js
let select = document.getElementById('pbvalue');

select.addEventListener('click', dodo);

function dodo(e) {
  if (e.target.value == 1) {
    alert('hi')
  } else {
    alert('no')
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="pbvalue" tabindex="4">
  <option value="0">""</option>
  <option value="1">100</option>
  <option value="2">200</option>
  <option value="3">300</option>
</select>
```

how to select different options, so different functions can fire according to that.

Comment: Just replace 'click' with 'change'. As we are changing the values, so you need to add 'change' as an event listener not 'click. Please go through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type, to know more about different type of events.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
let select = document.getElementById('pbvalue');

select.onchange = function () {
    // get the selected option
    var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value
}

// get all options:

for ( int i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++ ) {
    console.log( select.options[i].value )
}
```

This should give you an idea of how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

use `onchange` event.

```
<select  id="pbvalue" tabindex="4" onchange="dodo(event)">

      <option value="0" disabled>choose</option>
      <option value="1">100</option>
      <option value="2">200</option>     
      <option value="3">300</option>
             
</select>
```

```
<script>
      
          function dodo(e){
           switch(e.target.value){
               case "1":
                  alert(1);//do what ever you want
                  break;
               case "2":
                  alert(2);
                  break;
               case "3":
                  alert(3);
                  break;
               default:
                  alert("default");
                  break;
   
           }
       
         }
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `onChange` event on the `select` element.

```
<script>
    
    function onSelectChange() {
      const element = document.getElementById('pbvalue');
      console.log('Selected Index: ', element.selectedIndex);
      console.log('Selected Value: ', element.value);
    
    }
    
 </script>
    
    
 <select  id="pbvalue" tabindex="4" onchange="onSelectChange()">
    
          <option value="0">""</option>
          <option value="1">100</option>
          <option value="2">200</option>     
          <option value="3">300</option>
                 
    
 </select>
```